# append list defined in the module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using [bibtexparser](https://github.com/sciunto/python-bibtexparser) module available via pip for my project.
But, I need to expand the  `STANDARD_TYPES` list used in the code [bibdatabase.py](https://github.com/sciunto/python-bibtexparser/blob/master/bibtexparser/bibdatabase.py).

Can I append/redefine the list from my code?

Comment: `from bibtexparser import bibdatabase; bibdatabase.STANDARD_TYPES.add("whatever")`

Comment: You should fork the git project and change the list in your own repo. Then clone it, and build it locally with pip.

Comment: @mguijarr: This is giving me error:
    bibdatabase.STANDARD_TYPES.add("online")
AttributeError: module 'bibtexparser.bibdatabase' has no attribute 'STANDARD_TYPES'

Comment: maybe your file is not the same as the one from your link and your file is missing STANDARD_TYPES in bibdatabase module...? Well, you see the point - you can import the module and change its global variables if needed. It's Python, you're free :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are absloutely correct. The github and pip version is out of sync.